# How can I get cloudRoleName and cloudRoleInstance logged with Application Insights with a .NET Azure Container App?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-container-apps

When hosting an ASP.NET Core application on Azure Container Apps, cloudRoleName and cloudRoleInstance are currently not logged (or left empty) with Application Insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When initializing add a custom initializer like:

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Models;
using Utils;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
builder.Services.Configure<TelemetryConfiguration>((o) =>
{
    o.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new AppInsightsTelemetryInitializer());
});
```

and then initialize with

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

namespace Utils
{

    public class AppInsightsTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleName))
            {
                telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleName = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CONTAINER_APP_NAME") ?? "CONTAINER_APP_NAME-not-set";
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleInstance))
            {
                telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleInstance = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOSTNAME") ?? "HOSTNAME-not-set";
            }
        }
    }

}
```